# Guidelines for context edits and rewrites

Tags: support, faq, editing, context, merging

Suppose you come across a question that has been closed for lack of context, has high quality answers, and on its way to being deleted. Can you save the post by editing it to include more context?

Here is the deciding question:

> **Can the question be salvaged without changing the author's intent?**

So, what are some things you could do?

- You can fix or add MathJax.
- You can clarify the author's English or phrasing.
- You can add in relevant definitions, theorems, or simple background and motivation.
- You can add a source for the question.
- You can add context which was provided by the original author in the comments.

Now let's look at a few examples of actions that would change the author's intent.

- **Do not add an attempt.** Adding an attempt modifies the author's intent by adding presumed information about their background, prior knowledge, mistakes or lack thereof in earlier parts of the question, and their understanding of mathematics in general.
- **Do not expand the question with so much context that it changes fundamentally.** Doing so modifies the author's intent by presuming the author's level of sophistication and mathematical maturity.

Some might be thinking, "But what if the latter types of edits produce a great question?"

Well, yes. It is undeniable that one can write a great question by removing enough of a bad question and adding enough good. And math.se needs more great questions! However, we don't want to get into a [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) situation here. With few exceptions, a question should primarily remain the product of its author, while being *helped* and *improved* by editors, not *commandeered* by editors.

So, how can one save a question that can't be salvaged without changing the author's intent?

If the question is unsalvageable, you can rewrite it entirely by posting a new question. Here is the procedure:

1. Ask a new question that does include proper context. The new question must be well above what would normally be the bar for acceptability. It must be well-written, including background, motivation, source if applicable (especially for [contest-math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math)), etc. In particular, the context in the new question should not be an "attempt." If you're unable to formulate the question with context that is not an attempt, then the question is not valuable enough to be saved.
2. Leave a comment on the question stating your intent to rewrite their question.
3. Wait for 7 days. This gives the OP an opportunity to object to the rewrite.
4. Flag for the answers to be merged into the new question.

---

**Q: Which questions can be saved via a rewrite?**

First, let me stress two points:

- *Most questions do not need to be saved.*
- *Most questions that can be saved are salvageable through edits.*

It is crucial to note that the rewrite process uses moderator resources, which are a limited commodity. Therefore, to qualify for a rewrite merge:

- The original question must have at least one high quality answer.
- The new version must have meaningful, distinct substance from what is contained in the original, and provide notable value to future users.

Furthermore, at least one of the following must be true:

- The original is in direct risk of deletion, or has been subject to a delete/undelete war in the last 90 days.
- The original predates the new context standards (i.e., was asked prior to 2015).

**Q: What do I say in the comment warning the user that the question will be rewritten and merged?**

Link this post and the context section of [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

> I have rewritten your question to include [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) pursuant to the [rewrite guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402).  I have flagged this question to be [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158066/) with the [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/$FOO) in seven days. If you would prefer to edit context into your question yourself, **please raise a flag** before that time so that the merge may be delayed or cancelled.

Source for copy-paste:

```
I have rewritten your question to include
[context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) pursuant to the 
[rewrite guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402).
I have flagged this question to be 
[merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158066/) with the
[new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/$FOO) in seven days. If you would
prefer to edit context into your question yourself, **please raise a flag**
before that time so that the merge may be delayed or cancelled.
```

(Make sure to replace `$FOO` with the appropriate link.)

**Q: Should rewritten questions be Community Wiki?**

No. [Community wiki isn't a tool for reputation denial.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)

**Q: My question has been rewritten and I don't like the new version. What can I do?**

Edit [proper context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/12952) into your question prior to the merge date. If you need more time, raise a flag on your question (the original) requesting the merge be postponed. If the question has already been merged, this cannot be undone.

**Q: What sort of context can be edited into a question?**

The new question ought to contain motivation for the question and canonical background such as relevant definitions and theorems. In the case of textbook problems, it is a plus to add a citation to the source; in the case of contest math questions, this is a requirement.

Regardless of whether you are rewriting the question or editing context into the original question, **do not simply add an "attempt"**. In the case of editing context into someone else's question, adding an attempt changes the intent of the author, so it is disallowed. Posting a new question that includes an attempt will make it so we do not consider it a "rewrite" and thus it will not be eligible for merging, and will also be open to being closed as a duplicate.

**Q: When editing a question, should I signal that the parts that I add come from me and not the OP?**

No. We have revision history for that. In particular, don't use forum-like syntax such as "EDIT:" or "ADDED BY {your name}:" Each version of a post should read as though it was posted by a single author in its current form.

**Q: When is it appropriate to rewrite a question vs. edit context into the original question?**

Qualitatively, edit context into a question if it is salvageable, and rewrite only if the question absolutely cannot be salvaged.

To elaborate on this, there are many "solve my problem" questions which no amount of editing can save.  However, *a new question might put the particular problem into a broader context*, so that the original question becomes an abstract duplicate of the new question. If this can be accomplished while preserving the integrity of the original answers, merging them in improves future value of the question to other users, which can then serve as a duplicate target for similar questions.

Comment: This looks thorough to me. Possible typo, in the last paragraph, "so that the original question becomes an abstract duplicate of the original", should it be "so that the original question becomes an abstract duplicate of the new question."? Also, when you say moderator resources are limited, is this saying you're busy, or the site won't let you even if you wanted to do it a lot?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for catching that. Yes, when we say mod action is scarce, we mean that manual intervention from moderators is a finite resource, and thus not highly scalable. Therefore, we try to design policy so that we are exception handlers.

Comment: I think this is well thought out, but I have an issue with the merging suggestion. If the author of the original question is notified by a comment of a potential merge of answers into another question, and they don't want this to happen, then they now have a set time frame to fix their question. This places a lot of extra work on the original author, without knowing for sure if the author will even see the comment, (they might not visit S.E. regularly) or if the author has been notified early enough to do anything about it. (1 of 2)

Comment: Perhaps it may be better to duplicate the answers into the new question? In theory, the old one will have less votes than the new, and will be less likely to appear in google searches anyway. Doing it this way has less of an impact on the original author. (2 of 2)

Comment: What is the mod's opinion on [this edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124663/application-of-hilberts-basis-theorem-in-representation-theory)? It does not quite fall into the first category (Mathjax ....), but looks more like adding a failed attempt. In general I think working out a failed attempt, or just some particular case makes a valuable context. If the purpose of this post is to serve as a guideline in editing closed post, I hope the points can be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I had some thoughts churning around recent meta posts impinging on the etiquette/wisdom of all this.

Comment: In the sentence "In particular, the context in the new question should not be an "attempt."" Should I understand as "the new version should contains more than merely an attempt" or "an attempt should not appear in the new version"?

Comment: And this one: "Posting a new question that includes an attempt will make it so we do not consider it a "rewrite" and thus it will not be eligible for merging, and will also be open to being closed as a duplicate." I really don't understand why you hate attempts so much.

Comment: Related older discussions: [Editing someone else's question to add context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21106/42969) and [What kind of context is good to add to a contest math question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32223/42969)

Comment: I just wonder if this should be split into a question and an answer.

Comment: I think this is a well thought out procedure. I will adjust my practices on the rare occasions when I am prone to do something like this.

Comment: @user400188 as explained in the post they do have the option to say they need more time. Before merging we can also check if the account  was online or seems active.  In a case of an active account that just was not online this one week for whatever reason we might decide to give an extra delay. To the best of my knowledge it is not technically possible to duplicate the answers. If anyone is worried their questions are merged while they are away or they will need to fix it at an inconvenient time, the solution is simple, fix the questions already before somebody has the idea to do so for you.

Comment: @ArcticChar the intent is the latter, i.e., there should be no attempt. That said, the line can be somewhat blurry. If the new posts explains that the problem is interesting because contrary to similar problems some standard approach fails then this is not an attempt although the information could also be presented via an attempt, but it is not quite the same.

Comment: @MartinR I think this is a good idea down-the-road. For now, as long as people comment a lot and there might be tweaks, it seems simpler to have everything in one post.

Comment: I know this is marginal, but: if the poster's account is deleted, then it seems fine to add attempts and even change fundamentally the question, right? In this case writing a new question and ask for merging seems to be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @ArcticChar the advantage of having a new post is that the person that wrote the post owns it. Eg, if down the road somebody has a question and comments it'll notify the user competent to answer. (I know that it is in principle possible to get notified about comments on other posts and to notify editors the point stands though.) For attempts, generally, it is not clear what the point of an attempt is unless it is the actual attempt of the person that asks the question. Even then we hardly ever want attempts; we accept them because arguably for some users it is the only thing they can do.

Comment: @quid As some users who merely wants to preserve the content, I don't really see owning the post has any advantage. TBH I don't want to be pinged by post that I merely want it reopened. Also, in most situations the post concerned are done and dusted: the high quality answers are all there already. (And I still don't see what is wrong to directly edit the original post, if the poster's gone)

Comment: Although this seems well thought out, it does seems like a rather complicated and time-intensive system to preserve content. As I read it, for content to be preserved someone must put in a lot of effort, and then their work has to be "approved" by a moderator. Editing the original post requires much less time and effort on everyone's part.

Comment: @ArcticChar the advantage is not for you but for the future reader that might have a question. Your comment is a bit contradictory. Either your expectation is there won't be any comments then the concern about being bothered by them us unfounded or you expect there to be comments in which case it is better there is somebody that could answer them.  If you do not want it on your main account create a separate one for this particular purpose.  That a merge involves moderators is also a feature. The subject is controversial and thus this is a good thing.

Comment: @user1729 This is why we strongly suggest editing instead whenever possible (in particular in the first Q in the Q&A section). Rewrites should be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @user1729 "it does seems like a rather complicated and time-intensive system to preserve content" thus it is hoped you will chose the content you try to preserve especially carefully. Regarding the much less effort on everyone's part. Unfortunately that is not true as a lot of effort goes into pursuing and resolving conflicts related to this.

Comment: @quid: Concerning attempt, I agree that sometimes the attempts look more like noise (especially those given by confused students), but right now this guidelines seem to be totally neglect any possible value of partial attempts as valuable context, even claiming that merging request will not be entertained if the new question contains an attempt.... this I really can't agree.

Comment: @quid Yes, my comment left out my musings on what "much less time and effort" actually meant! @Alexander+quid I suppose I wrote my comment because I was wondering: do the moderators think their involvement for rewrites is a long-term solution to this problem? Or are you hoping/envisaging that not many people will put in the effort to rewrite a question?

Comment: @ArcticChar what is the rationale for including an attempt for a question to which you have answer-posts already? This makes no sense in my mind. As explained the same information can be conveyed in a way that is not an attempt. The down-side with an attempt is that it introduces some vagueness as to whether it works or does not work like this, in that sense it is virtually always less clear than the same information recorded differently.

Comment: @user1729 we'll see what happens. I don't expect many meaningful re-posts. If there will be it'll be a pleasant surprise. I really don't think that there will be that many as to become a burden.

Comment: I am referring to failed/partial attempt that adds values to the post. Like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124663/application-of-hilberts-basis-theorem-in-representation-theory) again. It does not matter if the post has answers or not, this is still good context IMO. @quid

Comment: @ArcticChar I fail to see how that concern is not covered by my first comment to you here. There is no need for this angst that moderators will refuse merges because something could be construed as attempt.

Comment: Then I refer you to my first comment in this post, @quid. As a guideline I wish it to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @ArcticChar My interpretation of the edit you are talking about is that it explains why the question is hard. It is *more* than an attempt.

Comment: That's a partial attempt assuming an exact condition. @user1729 Yes it's more than an attempt, but it is an attempt (That's the reason I ask [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites#comment144593_32402) earlier, and this is quid's [reply](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites#comment144600_32402)) my complain is really that quid's comment is not reflected in the guideline.

Comment: @ArcticChar while this is understandable it is impossible to anticipate every possible case. For the particular inquiry, an issue is that the question is rather atypical in that it asked to  provide the details of a proof of a published result that turned out to just not exist. Anyway, the content is imo not an "attempt" the distinguishing feature of an "attempt" is that the status of what is written is unclear to the author. Perhaps  D.E.S. explains something learned in a failed attempt; that does not mean that it is an attempt; also a  successful attempt isn't an attempt but an answer.

Comment: +1, this was long overdue, especially with lot of ongoing debate on closure / deletions. I hope this gets finalized soon with minor tweaks (if needed based on comments here). Thanks a lot to the mod team!!

Comment: Perhaps this "question"/statement should be designated a frequently asked question?  To aid in users' referencing it as needed?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Suppose you have a question which is self-contained and well-posed in terms of definitions and the question asked, and gets answers accordingly. Should another user be able to rewrite all the terminology to use what they decide are "standard terms," even to the extent it requires existing answers to be modified to make everything line up?

Comment: @rschwieb: any edits which invalidate the existing answers should be avoided at best. In a way such edits change the intent of the question. But if someone posts a new Q&A using standard terms let that be treated as a separate question independent of old one. I don't see we need to merge the two using this policy.

Comment: I have done something like that recently: edit 5 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3795243/revisions). In that case I also edited the answer. @rschwieb

Comment: One person's "standard terms" are not necessarily someone else's. For example, the comments below [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3794741/10513) demonstrate this, where wikipedia's "standard terms" are disputed. So I think it is often better to leave in non-standard terms.

Comment: @ArcticChar I agree that case is justifiable: it looks to m like the OP was grasping for the right word to describe something, and switching to the real one had minimal impact.  The scenario I have in mind is one in which the poster selects definitions and then an editor essentially decides to rename them.

Comment: There is no information about "merging" in this post; a less active user of SE/SO who recieves the comment warning of an imminent merge may not know what it entails. math.meta seems to have no info. The comment template currently has 142 chars left, which is enough for this meta.SE post [What is a "merged question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/) to be placed in it (perhaps turning "merge" into a hyperlink)? If space is a concern, know that the hyphen-spaced quote of the question title after the question number in the URL can be safely removed.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's a good idea. You should edit it in!

Comment: @AlexanderGruber done :) with 88 chars to spare